# image values from database become null

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

[image: the error messege is "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"]

the image from the database becomes null and does not appear on the website. in other case, the same image from the same database are appear. there are no mistyped variables, but can't load on the web. I've been trying to put the namespace where the image is, but still not working.
I'm still very new to codeigniter, i've tried my best to explain with my poor english.
please response if you have the answer, thankyou

InvenModel getinfo() function

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use CodeIgniter\Model;

    class InvenModel extends Model
    {
    public function getinfo($slug = false)
        {
            if ($slug == false) {
                return $this->findAll();
            }
            return $this->where(['slug' => $slug])->first();
        }
    }
?>
```

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Controllers;

    use App\Models\InvenModel;

    class inventori extends BaseController
    { public function detail($slug)
        {
            $data = [
                "title" => 'Detail Produk',
                "invent" => $this->InvenModel->getinfo($slug)
            ];

            return view('inventori/detail', $data);
        }
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td> <img src="<?= $invent['img']; ?>" class="img"></td> <!-- here the error message appears -->
        <td> <?= $invent['nama']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?= $invent['stok']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?= $invent['terjual']; ?> </td>
        <td> <a href="" class="btn btn-success"> Edit </a> </td>
        <td> <a href="" class="btn btn-danger"> hapus </a> </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please update your question with **InvenModel** **getInfo** function!

Comment: _"here the error message appears"_ - What error message? What does it say? If you get errors, then it's _crucial_ that you share those. Add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: When you say _"in other case, the same image from the same database are appear"_, what are those cases? What's the difference? Different slugs? According to your code, you'll get null back if it can't find a match for the given slug.

Comment: Did you checked your required data exists in your database?

Comment: I think you forgot to initialize your model in your controller class, e.g. `private $InvenModel = new InvenModel();`